# How to display groups of notices by dates one by one using Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So if im having a `notices` `table` where i store `title, body and date`.
Now i want to display it in the below format

```
2018-01-09
Title Body
abc   abc123
pqr   pqr123


2018-01-10
Title Body
mno   mno123
pqr   pqr123
```

So I have input for `start date` and `end date` which gets all notices between those dates.

```
$notices = App\Notice::whereBetween('date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->oldest('date')->get();
```

But now i dont know how to filter data by date and print one group of notices ex. `2018-01-09` first and then another group of notices ex. `2018-01-10` and so on.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: `date` is a string like `2018-01-10` or a `datetime`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Collection::groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby) method to group data by date field:

```
$notices = App\Notice::whereBetween('date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
           ->oldest('date')
           ->get()
           ->groupBy('date')
           ->toArray();

$group1 = $notices['2018-01-09'];
$group2 = $notices['2018-01-10'];
```