# How to use groupBy in an eager loaded model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to apply `groupBy` on the `notices` model by `notice_date` like so

```
$admin = Admin::with([
            'notices' => function($query) use($request)
            {
                $query->where('type', $request->notice_type)
                      ->whereBetween('notice_date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
                      ->oldest('created_time')->groupBy('notices.notice_date');
            }, 'user:id,name'
        ])->get();
```

As I want to print like this

```
2018-01-10
Admin_name notice1 notice2 notice3
John          abc    abc     pqr
Mary          mno    pqr     abc

2018-01-11
Admin_name notice1 notice2 notice3
abc          mno    pqr     abc
pqr          pqr    pqr     mno
```

But when I use the `groupBy` in the query it gives me an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'post.notices.id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Answer (score 4):

specify  the relation name in groupBy function

```
->groupBy('notices.notice_date');
```

Comment: I reckon this should be the accepted answer as it is way cleaner

Answer (score 0):

That's because any column you use in a `select statement` **must appear** in the group by clause. To begin you can try to do some changes in `app/database.php`

```
    'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false,
    ]
]
```

Although it is not recommended, rather you can try the following-

```
$admin = Admin::with([
        'notices' => function($query) use($request)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw('notice_date'))->where('type', $request->notice_type)
                  ->whereBetween('notice_date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
                  ->oldest('created_time')->groupBy('notice_date');
        }, 'user:id,name'
    ])->get();
```

You can read [this](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/) article for better understanding of `strict mode`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display admins by notices dates, you should load the data like this:

```
$notices = Notice::with('admin.user')
    ->where('type', $request->notice_type)
    ->whereBetween('notice_date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
    ->oldest('created_time')
    ->get();
```

Then use the `groupBy()` collections method as [you did before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173144/how-to-display-groups-of-notices-by-dates-one-by-one-using-laravel-5):

```
$grouped = $notices->groupBy('notice_date');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::with('items');

$items = collect($user->items);

unset($user->items);

$user->items = $items->groupBy('column');
```